# Mootools to jQuery conversion

Tags: jquery, mootools

How do I turn the following line into jQuery? I have a file that I am converting from Mootools to jQuery and this is where I am stuck.

```
var pollResultTemplate = $('pollResultTemplate').getElement('.pollResult').clone();
```

Edit:

Okay thanks, now that that is settled, I am stuck on this line:

pollResultTemplate.getElement('.pollResultLabel').setProperty('html', pollOptionLabel);

What is the jquery equivalent to that? What does this line do? I want to assume that it sets the class "pollResultLabel" as the active element so that the next few lines can manipulate that element?

Answer (score 1):

In MooTools:

- `$('myID')` is for ID. Correspondent to vanilla `document.getElementById('myID')` and jQuery's `$('#myID')`. In MooTools you can also use `document.id('myID')`
- `getElement` could be translated to `.find('.pollResult').first()`

Clone is the same.

**Note:** MooTools and jQuery can exist in the same document **and** MooTools can do everything jQuery can and a bit more. Just fyi.

Answer (score 1):

If in Mootool `$` for ID, You can pass CSS Selector into `$` function in jQuery.

Your code when turning into jQuery:

1st way:

```
var pollResultTemplate = $('#pollResultTemplate .pollResult').clone();
```

2nd way:

```
var pollResultTemplate = $('#pollResultTemplate').find('.pollResult').clone();
```

3rd way:

```
var pollResultTemplate = $(.pollResult, '#pollResultTemplate').clone();
```

Comment: Okay thanks, now that that is settled, I am stuck on this line:

pollResultTemplate.getElement('.pollResultLabel').setProperty('html', pollOptionLabel);

What is the jquery equivalent to that? What does this line do? I want to assume that it sets the class "pollResultLabel" as the active element so that the next few lines can manipulate that element?

Comment: `pollResultTemplate.find('.pollResultLabel').html(pollOptionLabel);`